# Using Monad Ops in a Free Monad interpreter

Tags: scala, scala-cats, free-monad

Suppose I have written an interpreter which has dependencies on other interpreters

```
def interpreter[S[_]](implicit kvs:KVS.ops[S, UUID, String]): Example ~> Free[S, ?]
```

Suppose my interpreter wants to surface events into a writer monad, so S has to be at least a writer monad, or a transform which contains a writer monad.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

For example I could create a free Monad wrapper on the writer monad to expose methods like `write` or `tell`.

```
def interpreter[S[_]](implicit kvs:KVS.ops[S, UUID, String], writer.Writer.ops[S]) = new (Example ~> Free[S, ?]) {
...
case MyMessage() =>
  for {
    _ <- writer.tell(Vector("My message was called"))
  } yield "Complete"
```

or I could use the MonadWriter typeClass for S and use imported functions to lift to a free?

```
type MyWriter[S[_]] = MonadWriter[M, Vector[String]]
def interpreter[S[_]:MyWriter](implicit kvs:KVS.ops[S, UUID, String]) = new( Example ~> Free[S, ?]) {
import Writer2FreeOps._
...
case MyMessage() =>
  for {
    _ <- tell(Vector("My message was called"))
  } yield "Complete"


object Writer2FreeOps {
    def tell[S[_], W](w:W)(implicit M:MonadWriter[S, W]):Free[S, Unit] =
      Free.liftF(M.tell(w))
}
```

I see that there is a FreeT monad, however I would think this would constrain the generic behaviour, if you had one interpreter that was a `KVS ~> Free[State, UUID, String]`, and another with validation that was `KVS ~> FreeT[Xor, State, UUID, String]`, the above example would be constrained on which one it could use? Or maybe another way is that if intepreter was Example ~> FreeT[Writer.. ], KVS would need to have a natural transformation from Free[S,?] to FreeT[Writer, S, ?] which seems a little cumbersome...